# Using asp.net core, how to view (log) backchannel communication for OAuth2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, oauth-2.0

I can view frontchannel communication via browser developer tools, but how can backchannel communication be viewed or logged to gain understanding of the flow?

Specifically, I want to see http traffic when authorization code is exchanged for tokens.

So far I have unsuccessfully tried:

1. Added to appSettings.json: "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Debug"
2. Added to Program.cs: ConfigureLogging(x => x.AddConsole())
3. Added to Startup.cs: app.UseHttpLogging (apparently available in .net 6 preview 4)

Thanks.

Comment: You _might_ need to turn it up to `Trace` levels to see the lowest-level details, as things like OAuth tokens aren't logged by default as they contain sensitive information.

Comment: In addition to what @MartinCostello said, enable PII logging `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;` (for development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @abdusco and @Martin.
Using the pointers you gave, I was able to locate more info.

For benefit of others, here is code snippet to add in Startup::Configure() and the source as reference:

```
IdentityModelEventSource.Logger.LogLevel = EventLevel.Verbose;
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
var listener = new TextWriterEventListener(new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput())
{
    AutoFlush = true,
});
listener.EnableEvents(IdentityModelEventSource.Logger, EventLevel.LogAlways);
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/jorrit/0712ed32534b45ccca393e4c86b08526